# Amazon AWS. How use the Resources key to create a new file system and mount points in Amazon EFS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-efs

I would like to create an Amazon AWS EBS ambient with a EFS.
I fallow [this tutorial](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/services-efs.html) but I don't know what "Uses the Resources key to create a new file system and mount points in Amazon EFS" means. I tried to skip this step however I got this error on deploy:

> Service:AmazonCloudFormation, Message:Template format error:
>   Unresolved resource dependencies [FileSystem] in the Resources block
>   of the template

What should I do in order to configure those resource keys?

Comment: The "Resources" key its referring to is the "Resources" section of the EB config file, which itself uses CloudFormation to create additional AWS resources in your EB environment. See: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environment-resources.html

Regarding your specific error, it sounds like you have a problem with your config file.  It would be easier to debug if you pasted the config that's causing that error.

Comment: In my case I had unspecified variables in `option_settings` section in `*.config` file. This section is for you to edit parameters such as `VPCId`, `SubnetA`, `SubnetB` or `FILE_SYSTEM_ID`, but the last one is needed when you already have `EFS` storage. I solved my issue by doing `FILE_SYSTEM_ID: fs-********`. Have you specified them at that time when you asked the question? More details usually are provided in a comment above in `.config` by supplier.